# Instagram Api: Can I get all users who liked my media?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Suppose my app in live mode and i want to get the users who likes my media.Can I get all the users who like my media? So the users who likes my media should also be authentitaced or to be given permissions. I mean do i need to redirect the url to all of them to pass the likes scope permission. Beacuse i need all the users' list. If I can get all the users' list who like my media, is there any pagination or i will get all users in one request? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to authenticate as yourself with scope `likes` and then you will be able to get your media's `likes` user list.

There is no pagination, it is limited to latest 120 likes (at least in the current API)